# Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now. - compiler-1.1.1.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1)

Tags: android, android-lifecycle, android-paging

I am trying to add below libraries into my app

```
   ext {
    roomLibraryVersion = '1.1.0'
    lifeCycleVersion = '1.1.1'
    }

//room data base
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:$roomLibraryVersion"
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomLibraryVersion"
annotationProcessor "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:$roomLibraryVersion"

//life cycle
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:$lifeCycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifeCycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifeCycleVersion"


// rx android
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.2'
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.14"
implementation 'android.arch.persistence.room:rxjava2:1.1.0'

//paging
implementation 'android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.0'
```

I am getting below exception while running the code. Can anybody please help me to solve this issue

```
Execution failed for task ':app:javaPreCompileDebug'.
> Annotation processors must be explicitly declared now.  The following dependencies on the compile classpath are found to contain annotation processor.  Please add them to the annotationProcessor configuration.
    - compiler-1.1.1.jar (android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:1.1.1)

  Alternatively, set android.defaultConfig.javaCompileOptions.annotationProcessorOptions.includeCompileClasspath = true to continue with previous behavior.  Note that this option is deprecated and will be removed in the future.
```

Comment: The exception asks to add annotation processor for lifecycle, did you try to do it? The version can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/adding-components).

Comment: Yes, I added annotation processor. But exit with the same error.

Comment: Did you add the one for lifecycle? Because it's not in the code that you posted above.

Answer (score 5):

Change:
`implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifeCycleVersion"`
to:
`annotationProcessor "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifeCycleVersion"`

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Kotlin, replace 'implementation' with 'kapt'

```
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:$lifecycle_version"
kapt "android.arch.lifecycle:compiler:$lifecycle_version"
```

And put this at the top of your app level Gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'kotlin-kapt'
```